# Int to Byte with same value

Tags: java, int, byte

I have and int and a byte, I need the byte value to be the same value as the int, All answers I have found end up like this:

```
int i = 234;
byte b = (byte) i;
System.out.println(b); // -22
int i2 = b & 0xFF;
System.out.println(i2); // 234
```

Now if my int is equaled to 234, i need my byte value when printed out to say 234, not -22, I understand why its printed out as -22 but its not what I need.

If anyone knows how to do this then please help me.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. `byte` can only store numbers between `-128` and `127`. When converting an integer that is not representable, loss of information is bound to happen.

To elaborate, when converting the `int` to `byte`, only the lowest 8 bits are considered. `234` is representable in these 8 bits but the result is a negative number (`-22`) because the MSB is 1. In your code, when you do

```
int i2 = b & 0xFF;
```

it renders the number back to 32-bit integer with all bits except the lowest 8 set to zero. Therefore, the result is the same number `234`.

Comment: Thanx for trying, but I litterly just figured it out and it worked

Comment: What manouti is trying to tell you is correct, you CAN NOT represent 234 with a (signed) byte - in the same way that you can not store (Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1) in an int without overflowing. The reason why your answer below "worked" has nothing to do with you printing a byte as 234.

Comment: Ya, I know what data is going through the code so I know there wont be an overflow unless I manually hardcode it so there is one, the number 234 isn't a number I'm working with, its an example I picked up from a previous post. byte b = (byte) 12; is what I was looking for and solved my problem and is the answer to my question. It seems you are taking my example to literal and not looking at what I originally asked, I asked how to make a byte store exact same value as an int when printed out, And I found the answer. What int I'm using isn't the problem. But I do see my example was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question of how to make a byte store the same value as an int when printed out is `byte b = (byte) intVariable;`. I understand 234 would not work as it exceeds the limit but I did not say I was using that number, It was an example I had given, though I understand now it was not helpful so sorry and thank you to all that tried.